# Excel: Find Date When Cumulative Total Is Reached

Tags: excel, sum

I need a  formula, preferably non-array (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER), to find the date for which a cumulative total is met or exceeded starting today and looking back in time.

**Scenario:** A pilot must have 3 landings in the last 90 days before they can carry passengers.

**Question:** How many days out of 90 remain since the last 3 landings were made? (day landings and night landings count towards the total 3)

```
                 Landings
    Date       Day    Night
    10/01/17    1
    10/25/17    2   
    11/10/17           1
    11/30/17    1

Today's Date: 11/30/17
```

The **correct answer is 54 days remain** (90 days minus 36 days since 10/25/17) until the pilot can no longer carry passengers.

**Now, what formula will give me this answer?!**

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: To return the date midway through the table based on your criteria is not possible without an Array formula or a VBA function.  What is your aversion to Array formulas?  Are you okay with VBA?

Comment: Do you want to count days remaining? Or something else?

Comment: I'd like to count days remaining. I'm fine with an array, I just wanted to see if there were a way to do it without the array for a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the choice is either an array or a helper column. Here is a possible array solution

```
=90-D2+INDEX(A3:A10,MATCH(TRUE,(SUM(B3:C10)-SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B3,0,0,ROW(B3:B10)-ROW(B3)+1,2))<3),0))
```

[image]

It uses offset and subtotal to work out the running total of flights up to a given row, then tests to see if when subtracted from the overall total (5) it leaves less than three flights.

It might be better to use a helper column starting in (say) F3 with the formula

```
=(SUM(B$3:C$10)-SUM(B$3:C3))<3
```

and match the first TRUE value in that rather than using the volatile OFFSET function

```
=90-D2+INDEX(A3:A10,MATCH(TRUE,F3:F10,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without an array if you are willing to add a column that shows the total number of landings on and after each date.  The formula for Days Until Expiration in the table below is:

`=INDEX(B3:B6,MATCH(C9,E3:E6,-1))+90-C8`

[image: Days Until Expiration Example]

You could also use iteration or goal seek to get the answer without an extra column, but that seems like way more effort than the problem merits.